# JMS Cluster x Distributed Queue

Tags: jms, weblogic12c

Does anybody know the difference in having a single queue pointing to a JMS Server targeting to a cluster server and having a distributed queue
pointing each queue to a JMS Server pointing to each target server from cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also post this question on Oracle Community and I found the answer.

Click [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4068657)!